# How to sort cards' on-screen positions by their suit?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, card-game, sorting

I have a 13 cards and sort button.

When I click that button, I want all the cards of each suit to be grouped-together on screen. So if I have 4 diamond cards in my 13-card hand, all 4 diamonds must be placed together in one part of the hand. If I had 4 spades then all 4 spades must be placed together in a separate part of the hand.

Here's an example of a sorted hand of cards - note how all the cards of each suit are placed together in a row:

[image: Screenshot of 13 cards in a row, in order clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades]

So far I tried to Sort using Linq. When I inspect the sort order using Debug.Log it seems to be working fine, but I don't know how to position the cards on screen according to their suits.

Here is the code I'm using so far.
Note: `UserServedcards` is the collection of 13 cards dealt into the player's hand.

```
if (!SortCardOrder)
{
    List<GameObject> cardOrder = null;
    cardOrder = this.userServedCards.OrderBy(go => go.name).ToList();    

    foreach (GameObject userServedCards in cardOrder)
    {
        if (!userServedCards)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sorting -->" + userServedCards);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can still do this with LINQ. But when you have a more complicated sorting logic than just comparing a specific field, then you need to pass a custom compare-function to `OrderBy`. [This question on stackoverflow should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby).

Comment: Hi @DeepakGaurav. I've edited your post to try to clarify what you're asking. Please feel free to make corrections if I've misunderstood you anywhere. To help you solve this, we'll need more details about how you've set up your game. Can you show us how you've set up one of your card objects? I notice you're currently sorting by name - how have you named these objects? Is the card's identity solely encoded in the name, or do you have a script attached that holds parameters like its suit and rank? How are these arranged in your scene? Are they inside a UI container, or some other structure?

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for Editing. And What I did is I created a resources folder from the resource folder I am instantiating cards at runtime. And I am shuffling the cards. To Your Questions:  I named that objects. no card is not solely encoded or any script attached to the objects. no, they are not inside UI container.  ScreenShot Of my Game: http://prntscr.com/m0vw1w